# Correctly shrink NTFS and Resize partition using linux

Tags: ntfs, fdisk

I am trying to resize a 160GB disk to fit on a 80GB disk,

I have tried 3 times to shrink my NTFS and resize the partition. Im using backtrack as a live CD to do this,

I use **ntfsresize** to the filesystem to 60GB
Then I use **fdisk** to delete the partition and then create a new partion starting at the same point but finishing at 60GB, I mark the partition bootable and give it an ID of 7 which is for NTFS then I write it to disk and reboot, I then get,

> "Operating system not found"

So then I used  ms-sys to repair the MBR which it said was successful, But now when I boot I get

> "Error loading operating system"

Any Ideas, luckily I have clonezilla backup of the 160GB disk and I just keep reimaging and then trying again but im stuck as to how to get it to work,

Comment: Did you put fdisk into sector mode ( -u switch or the u command )?  If not then you probably did not recreate the partition with the same start point since it probably wasn't originally on an even cylinder boundary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do all of my partition resizing with a [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=start) Live CD or USB stick and it's not let me down yet - it's a single-step operation in a GUI environment and there's no need to shrink manually and then use fdisk.

Might be worth reinstalling your image and giving it a try.

PS: Kudos for actually keeping a backup before trying the operation - many don't!

Comment: Downloading now.. Ill give it a go and let you know thanks for the pointer

Comment: That completely worked plus it shows you all the commands its running.  I dont know why I constantly do things the hard way!

Answer (score 2):

I just used **GParted** to do this successfully on an Ubuntu system, for both **vfat** and **ntfs** filesystems.